# XSD xs:list confusion

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing

Could anyone please explain to me the use of the `xs:list` datatype? This could fit nicely for my application, as the .xml file should have a list (of labels) that I need to create list of object with that label.   My question is: Do I have to loop through the items of the list (and fill a collection inside my programm with them) or is there some automated mechanism that fills a collection with a XML list?  If I have to do it manually, whats the difference between a `xs:list`and a string separated by whitespaces?

I hope I managed to get my question across!

EDIT: Im using Qt to parse XML. Probably the SAX route.

Comment: How do you parse your XML data? With Java? C#? If with Java, with JAXB, DOM, etc...? Please update your question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the class `QXmlQuery` does exactly what I wanted. 
Its method `bool QXmlQuery::evaluateTo ( QStringList * target ) const` requires a sequence of `xs:string` values and fills `target` with them.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `xs:list` then it will be parsed and exposed as a collection/array data structure if you are using code generators. If you just use a string separated by white spaces then it will be exposed as a regular string and you will be responsible for parsing.

The difference is only if you are using xsd based code generators. If you are parsing using low-level api's like SAX or DOM then there is no difference.

Comment: Pangea, you're a gentleman, by the way (you know why)... Please take a look at my post, too  - since we're working on this together :) - ... One item you forgot to mention is the validation bit... Cheers!

Comment: @PetruGardea yep missed validation...hard to remember and add every thing to make the post complete ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not indicating a specific processor (e.g. JAXB or XSD.EXE or etc.) one cannot be specific... Although, as a general rule, list (and unions for that matter) are poorly supported.

In an ideal world, tools are to see it is a list, and the generated code (in an XML to code binding scenario) should provide you with a field, type of array, that would give you the things parsed already. Where tools fall short, you have to do it by hand, no difference there.

However, if you also do validation, then at least each item in the list will be neatly validated for you; whereas without it, you're - again - on your own.

Comment: JAXB suuports xs:list with the @XmlList annotation:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Comment: Thank you, Blaise; just to be clear, I did not intend to imply JAXB is not supporting xsd:list/union; I was just listing possible processors... Still, the changes (many people didn't get) to how xsd:union was managed between 1.x and 2.x in JAXB, showed the length of pain tools have to go through in this space... XSD.EXE still (albeit obsolete now) offers only partial support to xsd:list.